# Elements of a struct when I declare it with a value

Tags: c++, struct

If I make a struct and in one of the elements of that struct I assign a value, whenever I declare that structure, will the element have the value instead of garbage?

For example:

```
typedef struct {
int var1 = 10;
int var2;
} coordinates_t;
```

Every time I create a variable of the type coordinates_t the element var1 of that variable will be 10?

If not, is there a way to do that or will I have to 0 every struct I create?

---

A code version of that question:

```
typedef struct {
int v1 = 10;
int v2;
} numbers_t;

numbers_t player1;
printf("%d", player1.v1);
//What will be the output?
```

Comment: `What will be the output?` why don't you run it and see.

Comment: Please don't tag c since this is invalid code.

Comment: You cannot _declare_ a struct more than once.

Comment: Please choose a language. C and C++ are **not** the same!

Comment: This is valid in C++11, I believe. I'm pretty sure it's not valid in C.

Comment: @celticminstrel: You are right. My question has been answered.

Comment: Anyway: what does "valor" mean here?? Sure you do not mean "value"?

Answer (score 0):

By "valor" I assume you mean "value".

I also assume C++11, since that syntax is not allowed with C++03.

Yes, you're default initializing the `int v1` with the value 10 every time you construct the struct.

Answer (score 0):

> _"Everytime I create a variable of the type coordinates_t the element var1 of that variable will be 10?"_

For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) yes.

```
typedef struct {
    int v1 = 10;
    int v2;
} numbers_t;

int main() { 
    numbers_t player1;
    printf("%d", player1.v1);
}
```

Output

```
10
```

[**Proof**](http://ideone.com/L3qmGg)

---

For [c](/questions/tagged/c) the code [fails to compile](http://ideone.com/9rVpZM).